# Why is my python lmfit leastsq fitting function being passed too many arguments?

Tags: python, scipy, least-squares, trilateration

I've tried to search for someone making the same mistake as me, but have had no joy! It's also my 1st post, so I apologise if it's badly explained or directed. Advice welcome.

The problem I am solving is: Finding the position of a receiver of some kind by measuring the distances to a number of known reference points. It's basic trilateration, and I am using least squares to do this.

I have successfully used the scipy.optimize lesatsq function already to do this, so I'm pretty sure my fitting function works. However, I want to be able to use some of the extra features that the lmfit Python package offers, and I'm struggling to translate it accross. Full attempt code is here: http://pastebin.com/4xbfkaCm

The lmfit minimize function sets up calls to my fitting function, (which is called residualfunct) as follows, with stationarray being a numpy array containing station locations and ranges and params being a dictionary of parameters to be used in the fitting function

```
position = minimize(residualfunct, params, args=(stationarray))
```

and my fitting function is defined as

```
def residualfunct(params, stationarray):

    X = params['solutionX'].value
    Y = params['solutionY'].value
    Z = params['solutionZ'].value
    result = numpy.array([s[3] - linalg.norm(array((X,Y,Z))-array((s[0],s[1],s[2]))) for s in stationarray])
    print result
    return result
```

When I run this code I get the TypeError:

> residualfunct() takes exactly 2 arguments (5 given).

as this call is made by the minimize function, I don't see what control I have over this. I can only imagine that this is being raised because I am passing an np.array as an argument, but this seems unavoidable. Can anyone see what I am doing wrong?

Thanks

Comment: You need to show the full traceback, since it will show what is calling the function and what it's passing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the call to `minimize`, change

```
args=(stationarray)
```

to

```
args=(stationarray,)
```

`args` must be a sequence (typically a tuple) whose elements are the arguments passed to the function.  To create a tuple of length 1, you need the extra comma.  When you write `args=(stationarray)` (without the extra comma), the parentheses have no effect, and it is the same as writing `args=stationarray`.  `minimize` then calls the function as `residualfunct(params, stationarray[0], stationarray[1], ...)`, which results in the error that you reported.

Comment: Thank you so much, this worked perfectly and (after fixing all the other problems I subsequently found :)) the code now works as I need it to. I'd upvote if I had enough reputation.